# How can I left-align each cell in an equation containing math symbols?

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, equations, align, amsmath

As the title already indicates I have an equation which contains multiple cells and I want the content of each cell to be left aligned. Following [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28664) I tried used `flalign` however this seems to just left-align the overall equation. The following is a small example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{flalign*}
  \textrm{Some stuff about } \rho & & \\
  \qquad \textrm{This is a really long equation and the following} \qquad & \textrm{should be left aligned} & \\
  \qquad \textrm{Short equation (should be left too)}              \qquad & \textrm{but quite a long one on the right though} &
\end{flalign*}

\end{document}
```

This example produces the following output (I put some remarks to indicate what I would like to achieve):

[image: output]

After doing some research I got the feeling that either of [these](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/150028/71787) [two](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/83522) approaches should do but I can't get it working.

Following the [first approach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/150028/71787) I tried:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{calc}

\newcommand*{\mbc}[2]{\makebox[\widthof{$F(\alpha)$}][#1]{$#2$}}

\begin{document}

\begin{flalign*}
  \mbc{l}{\textrm{Some stuff about } \rho} & & \\
  \qquad \textrm{This is a really long equation and the following} \qquad & \textrm{should be left aligned} & \\
  \qquad \textrm{Short equation (should be left too)}              \qquad & \textrm{but quite a long one on the right though} &
\end{flalign*}

\end{document}
```

Surprisingly the first line now seems to end up in the second cell (instead of being left aligned in the first cell):

[image: output with \mbc]

The [second approach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/83522) doesn't seem to work with math symbols:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\pushleft}[1]{\ifmeasuring@#1\else\omit$\displaystyle#1$\hfill\fi\ignorespaces}

\begin{document}

\begin{flalign*}
  \pushleft{\textrm{Some stuff about } \rho} & & \\
  \qquad \textrm{This is a really long equation and the following} \qquad & \textrm{should be left aligned} & \\
  \qquad \textrm{Short equation (should be left too)}              \qquad & \textrm{but quite a long one on the right though} &
\end{flalign*}

\end{document}
```

Gives the output:

```
$ pdflatex test.tex
[...]
! Undefined control sequence.
\pushleft #1->\ifmeasuring 
                           @#1\else \omit $\displaystyle #1$\hfill \fi \igno...
l.20 \end{flalign*}
```

Inserting additional `$$` doesn't help either. The closest I could get was by using `\omit` and `\hfill` however `\omit` seems to opt out of math mode so I need to insert additional `$$`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{flalign*}
  \omit $\textrm{Some stuff about } \rho$ \hfill & & \\
  \omit $\qquad \textrm{This is a really long equation and the following} \qquad$ \hfill & \textrm{should be left aligned} & \\
  \omit $\qquad \textrm{Short equation (should be left too)}              \qquad$ \hfill & \textrm{but quite a long one on the right though} &
\end{flalign*}

\end{document}
```

[image: output with \omit and \hfill]

It works however my IDE is marking the extra `$$` as errors all over the place which is definitely not pleasant. Also I'm not sure if this is a clean solution that will always work as expected.

Does anybody have an idea how to achieve cell-wise left-alignment in an equation containing math symbols? Or any comments on the latter `\omit`-`\hfill`-`$$`-approach?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Left-align all columns in equation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/562850/left-align-all-columns-in-equation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{flalign*}
 & \textrm{Some stuff about } \rho & & \\
  & \qquad \textrm{This is a really long equation and the following} && \textrm{should be left aligned} \\
  & \qquad \textrm{Short equation (should be left too)} & & \textrm{but quite a long one on the right though}
\end{flalign*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Example code for other alignments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{flalign*}
  \shortintertext{\texttt{Columns left-aligned:} } 
  & \textrm{Some stuff about } \rho  \\
  & \qquad \textrm{This is a really long equation and the following} && \textrm{should be left aligned} \\
  & \qquad \textrm{Short equation (should be left too)} & & \textrm{but quite a long one on the right though}
\end{flalign*}

\begin{flalign*}
  \shortintertext{\texttt{Columns right-aligned:} } 
  & \rlap{Some stuff about $\rho $} \\
  & & \textrm{This is a really long equation and the following}& & \textrm{should be right aligned}& \\
  & &\textrm{Short equation (should be rightt too)} && \textrm{but quite a long one on the right though}&
\end{flalign*}

\begin{flalign*}
  \shortintertext{\texttt{Left column centred, right column left-aligned: }}
  & \textrm{Some stuff about } \rho  \\
  & \begin{gathered} \textrm{This is a really long equation and the following}\\\textrm{Short equation (should be centred)}\end{gathered}
  & \begin{aligned} & \textrm{should be left aligned} \\
  & \textrm{but quite a long one on the right though}\end{aligned}&
\end{flalign*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, decent solution! Do you mind explaining why this works? Is it that - within `align` - even columns are right-aligned and odd columns are left-aligned and so we just omit the even ones?

Comment: No. People often misunderstand  the syntax with `&`: actually k alignment  points require 2k – 1 `&`: From the second column of alignment, a first `&` points out the beginning of a new column, and the second `&` points the exact alignment in that column. For the first column, it is not necessary to point out its beginning, whence the 2k – 1 ampersands. Here, in the first column, the alignment happens at the left margin, and using `&&`  means the beginning of the second column and its alignment point are at the same place.

Comment: How can I achieve centering or right-alignment then? Isn't that syntax ambiguous when it comes to those cases? Could you explain how I can achieve the first column to be centered and the second one to be left-aligned?

Comment: @a_guest: I added a code for these cases. Only the centred/left-aligned case requires a different syntax, using  `gathered` and `aligned`.

Comment: Thanks! However I don't get the hang of the second example (right-alignment). The syntax is `&&  1st  &&  2nd  &`, so the first column is preceded by `&&` while the second column is preceded by only `&` (the second ampersand indicating a new column) but includes a trailing `&`.  Despite this difference the alignment in both columns is the same. Why is this? Also this examples uses five `&` for two alignment points which is not `2k-1` as you pointed out in your previous comment. I'd like to understand the `align` syntax so I can apply it to general cases.

Comment: The normal structure of an `flalign` environment is `3` columns, hence 5 &. The second example indeed has 3 columns, but the first column has something in it only in the first row (Some stuff...), and its length is 0, due to `\rlap`. In the other rows, it's empty. So the right-aligned left column is really the second column, and the right column is the third. The trailing & is the alignment point just after the last word (hence it is right-aligned); strictly speaking, this one can be deleted, but I left it to make the structure more visible. Is that clearer?

Comment: So is it correct that for each `&` beyond the first one, even ones move on to the next column and odd ones determine the alignment in the respective column (while the first `&` determines the alignment in the first column)? However absence of any `&` seems to apply centering. Trying just `content` centers the content. Using `content &` also centers the content (while I expected right-alignment of the first (and only) column). Using `content &&` left-aligns the content (while I expected right-alignment again). Is there any documentation which defines the rules for parsing `&`-syntax?

Comment: A simple align environment with several lines, without any `&` is right-aligned, and the whole block is centred. I know only `amsldoc.pdf` and studied carefully  the examples in §3.6, experimenting a little to check if I understood well the ins and the outs of alignment.