# How can I make all of the columns in my aligned environment left-aligned?

Tags: equations, alignment

I am trying to produce a three line equation, aligned on the start of each line and on the plus signs. I have tried this

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
     &1\cdot \varepsilon_1&+ 1\cdot \varepsilon_2 &+ \dots + 1\cdot \varepsilon_n\\
     &X_{21} \cdot \varepsilon_1 &+ X_{22} \cdot \varepsilon_2 &+ \dots + X_{2n} \cdot \varepsilon_n\\
     &X_{k1} \cdot \varepsilon_1 &+ X_{k 2} \cdot \varepsilon_2 &+ \dots + X_{kn} \cdot \varepsilon_n \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Which produces this

[image]

I tried replacing the 1's in the first line with X_{21}, X_{22} etc as in the second line, and it aligns properly then, but when I use 1's again, the equations go back to being unaligned again.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Remember there needs to be 2n-1 `&` on each line. n for alignment columns, and n-1 to separate the alignment columns. In this case I'se use `\begin{alignedat}{3}` for better spacing

Comment: How should the `1` terms be aligned: to the left, centered, or to the right? Please advise.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Left-align all columns in equation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/562850/left-align-all-columns-in-equation)

Comment: For center align see also [Control the alignment of each "cell" in amsmath's aligned environment - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150026/control-the-alignment-of-each-cell-in-amsmaths-aligned-environment)

Answer (score 2):

Remember 2n-1 `&`'s on each line with `n` alignments. `n` `&`'s for alignments and `n-1` `&`'s to separate the alignment columns. I'd also use `alignedat` instead as in this example

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{alignedat}{3}
     &1\cdot \varepsilon_1 &&+ 1\cdot \varepsilon_2 &&+ \dots + 1\cdot \varepsilon_n\\
     &X_{21} \cdot \varepsilon_1 &&+ X_{22} \cdot \varepsilon_2 &&+ \dots + X_{2n} \cdot \varepsilon_n\\
     &X_{k1} \cdot \varepsilon_1 &&+ X_{k 2} \cdot \varepsilon_2 &&+ \dots + X_{kn} \cdot \varepsilon_n \\
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Do you know where the documentation on the 2n-1 syntax is?

Comment: See section 3.6 in http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/amslatex/english/amsldoc.pdf and extrapolate from that

Answer (score 1):

Here are three more `array`-based solutions. One each depending on whether the cell contents should be left-aligned, centered, or right-aligned. Observe that contents of the three `array` environments are identical; they only differ in the use of the `L`, `C`, and `R` column types.

A separate topic: The code uses `\cdots` rather than `\dots`, as LaTeX doesn't "know" that the dots will be flanked by `+` (a binary operator) on either side -- but in the adjacent cells.( If `+\dots+` is found, LaTeX is smart enough to change `\dots` to `\cdots`.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class

\usepackage{array} % for '\newcolumntype' macro
\newcolumntype{O}{>{{}}c<{{}}} % for operators ( + , \cdot )
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\displaystyle}c}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\displaystyle}l}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\displaystyle}r}

\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'gather' environment

\begin{document}

\setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.33}
\begin{gather}
\begin{array}{ *{6}{LO} L }  % left-aligned
1      &\cdot& \varepsilon_1 &+& 1       &\cdot& \varepsilon_2 &+& \cdots &+& 1      &\cdot& \varepsilon_n\\
X_{21} &\cdot& \varepsilon_1 &+& X_{22}  &\cdot& \varepsilon_2 &+& \cdots &+& X_{2n} &\cdot& \varepsilon_n\\
X_{k1} &\cdot& \varepsilon_1 &+& X_{k 2} &\cdot& \varepsilon_2 &+& \cdots &+& X_{kn} &\cdot& \varepsilon_n
\end{array} 
\\[2\jot]
\begin{array}{ *{6}{CO} C }  % centered
1      &\cdot& \varepsilon_1 &+& 1       &\cdot& \varepsilon_2 &+& \cdots &+& 1      &\cdot& \varepsilon_n\\
X_{21} &\cdot& \varepsilon_1 &+& X_{22}  &\cdot& \varepsilon_2 &+& \cdots &+& X_{2n} &\cdot& \varepsilon_n\\
X_{k1} &\cdot& \varepsilon_1 &+& X_{k 2} &\cdot& \varepsilon_2 &+& \cdots &+& X_{kn} &\cdot& \varepsilon_n
\end{array} 
\\[2\jot]
\begin{array}{ *{6}{RO} R }  % right-aligned
1      &\cdot& \varepsilon_1 &+& 1       &\cdot& \varepsilon_2 &+& \cdots &+& 1      &\cdot& \varepsilon_n\\
X_{21} &\cdot& \varepsilon_1 &+& X_{22}  &\cdot& \varepsilon_2 &+& \cdots &+& X_{2n} &\cdot& \varepsilon_n\\
X_{k1} &\cdot& \varepsilon_1 &+& X_{k 2} &\cdot& \varepsilon_2 &+& \cdots &+& X_{kn} &\cdot& \varepsilon_n
\end{array}
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh, a `O` column for binary operators. Nice! Hadn't thought of that.

Comment: I think your explanation about `\dots` vs `\cdots` are a little wrong. Here we have to use `\cdots` as `\dots` cannot see the `+` in the other cells and thus cannot act accordingly.

Comment: @daleif. Thanks. I changed the explanation -- is it better now?

Comment: I think it is much clearer